# How to convert float to int without losing the decimal ? Just like it's shown in memory

Tags: c#, .net

Let's assume `float f = 4.4`

If I browse `f` in some memory reader and assume that `f` is an `int` I get the value 1082969293.

I don't want to cast it to int like `(int)f`

Is there a way to assume f as int and get that value(1082969293) in C# ?

Comment: When you say "similar to 1151354611" do you mean actually `1082969293`?

Comment: Yes, already Lee answered correctly and will be accepted in 2 mins.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
float f = 4.4f;
var bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(f);
int i = BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes, 0);
```

Comment: And a quicker way to do it (losing the explaining variable) would be `int i = BitConverter.ToInt32(BitConverter.GetBytes(f), 0);`  Pick which ever is more readable to you and your colleagues.

Comment: @Tory Only quicker to type, I think.  I suspect the compiler optimizes that variable away.  That said, I mildly prefer the more concise way, because `var bytes` doesn't really communicate any additional information over `GetBytes`.

Comment: @TimGoodman The Jitter may compile it away, but even with optimization on, the compiler still makes the local variable and uses the stloc.# and ldloc.#.  But, yeah, that's just low level pedantry.